# cannot import name 'INPUT_SHAPE' from 'utils'

Tags: python, import, training-data

I want to run the code

```
from utils import INPUT_SHAPE, batch_generator
```

First, it was giving the error

```
<No module named utils>
```

When I solved that, now running that code line is giving this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'INPUT_SHAPE' from 'utils' 
    (C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\utils\__init__.py)
```

The whole code I'm trying to implement is:

```
import pandas as pd # data analysis toolkit - create, read, update, delete datasets
import numpy as np #matrix math
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split #to split out training and testing data 
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from keras.layers import Lambda, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dropout, Dense, Flatten
#helper class to define input shape and generate training images given image paths & steering angles
from utils import INPUT_SHAPE, batch_generator
import argparse
import os

#for debugging, allows for reproducible (deterministic) results 
np.random.seed(0)


def load_data(args):
    """
    Load training data and split it into training and validation set
    """
    #reads CSV file into a single dataframe variable
    data_df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), args.data_dir, 'driving_log.csv'), names=['center', 'left', 'right', 'steering', 'throttle', 'reverse', 'speed'])

    #yay dataframes, we can select rows and columns by their names
    #we'll store the camera images as our input data
    X = data_df[['center', 'left', 'right']].values
    #and our steering commands as our output data
    y = data_df['steering'].values

    #now we can split the data into a training (80), testing(20), and validation set
    #thanks scikit learn
    X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=args.test_size, random_state=0)

    return X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid


def build_model(args):
    """
    NVIDIA model used
    Image normalization to avoid saturation and make gradients work better.
    Convolution: 5x5, filter: 24, strides: 2x2, activation: ELU
    Convolution: 5x5, filter: 36, strides: 2x2, activation: ELU
    Convolution: 5x5, filter: 48, strides: 2x2, activation: ELU
    Convolution: 3x3, filter: 64, strides: 1x1, activation: ELU
    Convolution: 3x3, filter: 64, strides: 1x1, activation: ELU
    Drop out (0.5)
    Fully connected: neurons: 100, activation: ELU
    Fully connected: neurons: 50, activation: ELU
    Fully connected: neurons: 10, activation: ELU
    Fully connected: neurons: 1 (output)

    # the convolution layers are meant to handle feature engineering
    the fully connected layer for predicting the steering angle.
    dropout avoids overfitting
    ELU(Exponential linear unit) function takes care of the Vanishing gradient problem. 
    """
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Lambda(lambda x: x/127.5-1.0, input_shape=INPUT_SHAPE))
    model.add(Conv2D(24, 5, 5, activation='elu', subsample=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Conv2D(36, 5, 5, activation='elu', subsample=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Conv2D(48, 5, 5, activation='elu', subsample=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, 3, 3, activation='elu'))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, 3, 3, activation='elu'))
    model.add(Dropout(args.keep_prob))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(100, activation='elu'))
    model.add(Dense(50, activation='elu'))
    model.add(Dense(10, activation='elu'))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.summary()

    return model


def train_model(model, args, X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid):
    """
    Train the model
    """
    #Saves the model after every epoch.
    #quantity to monitor, verbosity i.e logging mode (0 or 1), 
    #if save_best_only is true the latest best model according to the quantity monitored will not be overwritten.
    #mode: one of {auto, min, max}. If save_best_only=True, the decision to overwrite the current save file is
    # made based on either the maximization or the minimization of the monitored quantity. For val_acc, 
    #this should be max, for val_loss this should be min, etc. In auto mode, the direction is automatically
    # inferred from the name of the monitored quantity.
    checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('model-{epoch:03d}.h5',
                                 monitor='val_loss',
                                 verbose=0,
                                 save_best_only=args.save_best_only,
                                 mode='auto')

    #calculate the difference between expected steering angle and actual steering angle
    #square the difference
    #add up all those differences for as many data points as we have
    #divide by the number of them
    #that value is our mean squared error! this is what we want to minimize via
    #gradient descent
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=Adam(lr=args.learning_rate))

    #Fits the model on data generated batch-by-batch by a Python generator.

    #The generator is run in parallel to the model, for efficiency. 
    #For instance, this allows you to do real-time data augmentation on images on CPU in 
    #parallel to training your model on GPU.
    #so we reshape our data into their appropriate batches and train our model simulatenously
    model.fit_generator(batch_generator(args.data_dir, X_train, y_train, args.batch_size, True),
                        args.samples_per_epoch,
                        args.nb_epoch,
                        max_q_size=1,
                        validation_data=batch_generator(args.data_dir, X_valid, y_valid, args.batch_size, False),
                        nb_val_samples=len(X_valid),
                        callbacks=[checkpoint],
                        verbose=1)

#for command line args
def s2b(s):
    """
    Converts a string to boolean value
    """
    s = s.lower()
    return s == 'true' or s == 'yes' or s == 'y' or s == '1'


def main():
    """
    Load train/validation data set and train the model
    """
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Behavioral Cloning Training Program')
    parser.add_argument('-d', help='data directory',        dest='data_dir',          type=str,   default='data')
    parser.add_argument('-t', help='test size fraction',    dest='test_size',         type=float, default=0.2)
    parser.add_argument('-k', help='drop out probability',  dest='keep_prob',         type=float, default=0.5)
    parser.add_argument('-n', help='number of epochs',      dest='nb_epoch',          type=int,   default=10)
    parser.add_argument('-s', help='samples per epoch',     dest='samples_per_epoch', type=int,   default=20000)
    parser.add_argument('-b', help='batch size',            dest='batch_size',        type=int,   default=40)
    parser.add_argument('-o', help='save best models only', dest='save_best_only',    type=s2b,   default='true')
    parser.add_argument('-l', help='learning rate',         dest='learning_rate',     type=float, default=1.0e-4)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    #print parameters
    print('-' * 30)
    print('Parameters')
    print('-' * 30)
    for key, value in vars(args).items():
        print('{:<20} := {}'.format(key, value))
    print('-' * 30)

    #load data
    data = load_data(args)
    #build model
    model = build_model(args)
    #train model on data, it saves as model.h5 
    train_model(model, args, *data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

***EDIT***

I checked for utils.py files in anaconda3 folder and found 9 of them. I also checked for INPUT_SHAPE in each of the python file but couldn't find it any one of them. [9 files of utils.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIbyy.png)

[enter image description here][2]

Comment: Can you supplement the question with a description of the directory structure in which these files (the file you are importing into and the file utils.py) are stored? 
If utils is a package, not a module, then also show the structure of this package, indicating where the objects INPUT_SHAPE and batch_generator are stored.

Comment: are you sure it should be `INPUT_SHAPE` ? maybe it should be `input_shape`? Error shows you path to module `utils` and you can open it in text editor to see if `INPUT_SHAPE` really exists in this module.

Comment: I check `from utils import INPUT_SHAPE, batch_generator` in Google and I found it in [How_to_simulate_a_self_driving_car](https://github.com/llSourcell/How_to_simulate_a_self_driving_car) and maybe you have two files `utils.py` and it imports different `utils` then you expect - it can happend when you run code in different folder then folder with `utils.py` and then it can't find it. Check `Current Working Directory` - `print( os.getcwd() )` - to see in which folder it runs your code. If it is wrong folder then you may need to change it  - ie. `os.chdir(...)` - before importing

Comment: you have the same code as in [model.py](https://github.com/llSourcell/How_to_simulate_a_self_driving_car/blob/master/model.py) and I sure your problem is you have two different module - `utils.py` and `utils/__init__.py` and it loads wrong module - probably because you run code in wrong folder and `import` search it in different folder then you expect. You have to go to folder with code and then run it. You can't run it as `path/to/script.py` from other folder because then it will search `utils.py` in other folder

Comment: @furas  The `print( os.getcwd() )`  command gives me `C:\Users\Lenovo` . I guess it's the right directory?
Also, I have 9 different utils.py files. I checked for INPUT_SHAPE in each one of them but couldn't find this in any of the files. (I've edited my question in this regard, please check it)
Now what?

Comment: @zanuda Can you tell me how do i find out the directory structure?

Comment: The first thing you need to do is find the module or package that contains the requested objects (INPUT_SHAPE and batch_generator). 
The next step is to make python look for modules and packages in the directory where you find your module or package. You can see with these commands where python looks for modules and packages:
`import sys; print(sys.path)`

Comment: Isn't finding the module or package which contains the requested objects a very tedious task? Like do I have to open each and every python file and look for the object?
PS: Please excuse my dumbness. I'm totally new to this.

Comment: Well, there are many utilities for searching through files. In Linux, you can use the grep utility. Windows also has a built-in tool in or you can use Total Commander or Notepad++.

Comment: I added the vast directory 'site packages' through `sys.path.append('C:Users/Lenovo/anaconda3/Lib/site-packages')`
This directory is the main directory that has all the modules and packages, every file comes under it. But this isn't still solving the problem

Comment: if you found `utils` without `INPUT_SHAPE` then you don't have correct `utils.py`. In example [How_to_simulate_a_self_driving_car](https://github.com/llSourcell/How_to_simulate_a_self_driving_car) they have own `utils.py` with `INPUT_SHAPE` and it is in the same folder as `model.py` which has the same code as you. Maybe you got only `model.py` but you forgot to get other files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  found your code in project [How_to_simulate_a_self_driving_car](https://github.com/llSourcell/How_to_simulate_a_self_driving_car) in file `model.py`. This project has also file `utils.py` with `INPUT_SHAPE`.

It looks like you copy file `model.py` but you forgot to copy file `utils.py`.

You should have both file in the same folder - ie. `C:\Users\Lenovo` - and start `python model.py` from this folder `C:\Users\Lenovo`

So copy `utils.py` from project `How_to_simulate_a_self_driving_car` to your project.

But it would be better to copy all files from project `How_to_simulate_a_self_driving_car` because it may need other files from this project.

Comment: I have actually cloned this whole Git repository. The location for that is `C:\Users\Lenovo\How_to_simulate_a_self_driving_car`.  And I've rechecked that both the files are there. So that means both are in the Lenovo directory right?

Comment: I opened Jupyter notebook directly from `C:\Users\Lenovo\How_to_simulate_a_self_driving_car` (  directory where the git repository was cloned) and it worked! Thankyou @furas